# Can't achive fully opaque pixels on my pixel-art character

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency, pixel-art

I am creating pre-rendered pixel art character, but it renders many pixels semi transparent. The resolution is 60x60 and I use set alpha node, but it somehow doesn't work. I made a few characters with older blender versions and I used the same technique and never had problem with it. It doesn't work in both cycles and eevee. Many would suggest setting sampling on 1, but the result is rather ugly and I never changed the sampling in my previous projects.
Is it a bug of 2.9 version or is there something i forgot about?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason to use the Separate node to get the Alpha, instead of using the Render Layer Alpha output socket?

Comment: Also, if you want transparent background, you can just enable transparent background in the render settings, try it with that if it will be still semi transparent

Comment: It returns the same result with separate node and without it.

Comment: And i have the transparent background enabled.

Comment: What if you disconnect the Greater Than from the Set Alpha and manually set the Alpha to 1.0? Does that change things or do you get the same result?

Comment: I get the same result even when i set it manually.

Comment: @MatejŠevčík Check that you have 'Compositing' enabled in the Post Processing section of the Output Properties. It sounds like maybe your compositor nodes aren't actually being applied after your render.

Comment: Compositing is enabled. When it is disabled, the render looks the same though.